# scrollable and non scrollable images

Tags: android, layout, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to build a gui for my app. It is comprised of two images, one on top of the other. The bottom image needs to be scrollable, the top image needs to be fixed.

This is the current layout xml for the view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_load"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Load" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_save"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <uk.co.test.EditorView
        android:id="@+id/EditorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/imagemdpi" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Using this layout, the bottom image does not scroll, it is compressed to the width of the screen. If I remove the EditorView, it does scroll. How can I make the gui act as I want?

Any help gratefully received. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually not sure why removing the EditorView makes it work. Also, I only see one image view in your layout. But to make that ImageView scroll horizontally, I would change the layout_width of the scroll view to "match_parent" and add a scale type to your image view.

(see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html )

I would try either "center" or "matrix," although usually I have to play around with these a bit to get it to work just how I want it.
so:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/imagemdpi" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

In generally, with scroll views, you want to match_parent for the size of the scroll view, but wrap_content for the view being scrolled. The scroll view will allow the wrapped view to grow bigger than its own bounds, but if the scroll view grows bigger than the screen bounds, it won't scroll because it thinks it's showing everything already.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it now works :). EditorView contained an ImageView, I thought I'd try putting the ImageView in instead, and set layout_width for the HorizontalScrollView to match_parent as you advised, and put the scaletype in, using "center".
Thanks again.

Comment: @JulioM Please accept my answer if it works for you. It helps my reputation, and also helps future users find the correct solution if they have a similar problem.